# Send 404 status code on a specific WordPress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

I need to send a 404 status code on a specific page in WordPress. The page is not using the 404.php template. Preferably, I would like to do it within my theme files, and not using .htaccess.

Here is what I have that's not working.

```
function my_404() {
  if ( is_page( 813 ) ) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
    echo 'Testing123'; //This outputs fine, so I know the code is running on the correct page
  }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'my_404' );
```

If successful, the page would look the exact same, except running it through a website analyzer would tell me it's returning a 404 code. However, using this code, it still returns 200 no matter what.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, that should get you the expected result:

```
function my_404() {
  if ( is_page( 813 ) ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->set_404();
    status_header(404);
    nocache_headers();
  }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'my_404' );
```

Comment: It still returns HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: See my edit, try adding nocache_headers() to the function. The general idea should definitely be correct since it worked for me before.
Also please make sure the page is not cached in your browser etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook before the actual query is run:

```
    function my_404( $query ) {
        if ($query->queried_object_id == 813) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
            die('Testing123');
        }
    }
    
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_404' );
```