# URL redirection: WordPress with plugin redirection

Tags: wordpress, url, redirect

Someone attacked me with a lot of Google Ads traffic and made the bounce on my website increase and caused the ranking on [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) to fall. In this case, I want to do a redirect URL with parameters like the following:

Source: mydomain.com/?gclid=blablabla

To: mydomain.com/404

All URLs with this parameter I want to redirect to the 404 page. Currently I am using WordPress and a redirection plugin. How can I fix this?

I want to change target URL to 404 from all these parameters: /?gclid=

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send 404 status code on a specific WordPress page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245385/send-404-status-code-on-a-specific-wordpress-page)

Answer (score 0):

While this is technically a duplicate question, it varies slightly, because the information is available immediately, rather than only after WP loads.

I don’t know that this can be solved properly with Redirection plugin. If the plugin can identify the query parameter `gclid` then you could redirect to a URL that doesn’t exist (as you’ve suggested), but that’s probably not best.

Untested code to add in MU-plugin:

```php
// If no query parameter, let it through.
if ( ! isset( $_GET['gclid'] ) ) {
    return;
}

// Send 404 status and prevent caching.
status_header( 404 );
nocache_headers();

// Prevent further processing.
exit;
```

Answer (score -2):

To redirect URLs with the parameter `/?gclid=` to a 404 page using WordPress and a redirection plugin, you can follow these steps:

1. Install and activate a redirection plugin on your WordPress website. Some popular options are "Redirection" or "Simple 301 Redirects."
2. Once the plugin is activated, go to the plugin settings or find the redirection menu in your WordPress dashboard.
3. Look for an option to add a new redirection rule or create a new redirect. This may vary depending on the plugin you are using.
4. In the source URL field, enter `/?gclid=` (without quotes). This will match any URL that has the `/?gclid=` parameter.
5. In the target URL field, enter "/404" or the URL of your 404 page. This will be the destination where the redirected traffic will be sent.
6. Save the redirection rule and test it by visiting a URL with the `/?gclid=` parameter to see if it redirects to the 404 page.

Comment: A custom 404 page is not necessary for search engines to understand the 404 status code. It’s necessary for a positive user experience, but not for search engines.

Comment: DO NOT create a 404 page in the WordPress admin to redirect to. This will send a 200 status code to browsers and search engines, which will continue the problem.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: @DavidW: That *may* be a false positive.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Maybe - I'm pretty confident about https://stackoverflow.com/a/76387325/ but could be wrong about this one (which was posted shortly after)